# Extensive form notation in game theory

Tags: game-theory

I'm struggling to understand the notation surrounding an extensive form game. I've taken this example from the Wikipedia page for [subgame-perfect equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgame_perfect_equilibrium).

So for this game: [subgame example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSeEp.png) I don't understand the matrix notation (given on the Wiki page - can't post more than two images...). Does (K,K) mean player 1 chooses K, then sees player 2s choice and decides to stick with K? If so, shouldn't L (K,U) be (1,3)?

Thanks

Comment: This question is about mathematics, not programming or software.  Try [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) or [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: @WillVousden I assumed as there exists a game-theory tag, any questions on game theory would be welcome.

Comment: I think this site is best suited to practical problems concerned with implementation.  Since yours is a theoretical question, I think it's better suited to other sites on SE, where you'll get a better audience.  To be honest, I'm not sure why that tag exists here... At any rate, it's only been used 126 times, vs. [1574 on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-theory)!